# Mongoose populate first and then filter based on populated field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I have two collections (`items`, and `subitems`). The `items` collection has an object reference to subitems collection in `subItems` property (It's an array of subItem ObjectIds).

I want to build a query where I can first populate the `subItems`, and then filter based on populated field. I tried running the query below, but it seems that populate is ran last, therefore `subItems[0].sharedGroups.groupId` can never be filtered properly because it's not populated yet.

```
db.items.find({
        $or: [
          { 'owner': 1 },
          { 'subItems[0].sharedGroups.groupId': { $in: [3691] } },
        ]
}).populate('subItems');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `$lookup` and then `$match` in aggregation like this

```
db.items.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup:{
      from:"subItems",
      localField:"subItems", // field of reference to subItem
      foreignField:"_id",
      as :"subItems"
    }},
  {
    $match:
        {
          $or: [
            { 'owner': 1 },
            { 'subItems.sharedGroups.groupId': { $in: [3691] } },
          ]
        }
  }]
  )
```

Comment: Seems ok but ```subItem.sharedGroups.groupId``` is not returning anything . I edited my question because subItem is actually an array (subItems)

Comment: I added $unwind and it works as I want it now

Comment: I didnt know type of that if you want add sample data to complete my answer